# Choosing "unavailable" pickup point in online shop

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools, online-store

just discovered one bug in a "n" online shop. The bug is the possibility to change html code (thanks to inspect element) and make an early unavailable pickup point available. As consequence, I was able to order some stuff, pay, and even get confirmation of my order. My question is, how an owner can prevent something like this?

P.s. During ordering, I was only on the one web page, there was no redirecting to another page or refreshing the current, until payment.

P.s.s. just want to mention, that I'm a total newbie in these "magic" things. So probably you can recommend me books/webpages etc. where I can read more about "server responses".

Comment: You can add validation for the location in the server side and prevent from going to payment page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found out, editing the HTML code of a site and/or modifying the data sent to or from your browser is indeed not too difficult. That's part of how a browser is designed and intended to work, so you'll have to deal with this kind of "hacking" on the server side.

Here's a very superficial (and not complete) list of things to keep in mind when setting up your server and backend application:

- ***Every request from outside ("the client") is potentially malicious or tampered with***. → Make sure you use server-side validation for "everything". This may refer to:

  - Input fields (length, value, format, ...)
  - Data formats (e. g. correct JSON/XML structure)
  - User authentication and authorization
  - Your business rules (this is, as I think, the one decisive in your example - probably everything else was valid, but the server side did not check for the availability of that pickup point you injected)
- Thus, do ***never* rely on client-side validation** (typically JavaScript / TypeScript) only! You can use this for a better user experience, but the real "hard" validation must take place on the server side.
- Depending on the criticality of your site and the confidence of the data associated, think about **adding more security by using a Web Application Firewall (WAF), rate limiting, log crawling** and other techniques to identify and block suspicious traffic.
- **Keep your server software** (the operating system with all its libraries etc., the application server (like Apache / Nginx / WildFly / ...) and the software your site comprises of (like a Spring / PHP / Angular / ... application)) **up to date**. There are means and methods like [Dependabot](https://github.com/dependabot) helping you to automatize this process. Outdated software and libraries might have some known bugs an attacker can exploit.
- Try to **use standard software, frameworks and mechanisms wherever possible**. Modern Web Frameworks like Spring Boot, Laravel, ... are well-maintained and security issues are found and fixed early. Also, the have validation and fraud detection methods built-in already, you'll just have to make use of them. On the other hand, if you try to code your own authorization framework (for example), you'll most likely overlook something and leave a security gap.